# MS Dynamics CRM 2011 and Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am trying to learn the Dynamics CRM 2011programming with the help of SDK samples.
We have Visual Studio 2008 which can't target .net 4.0 framework

Do i need to buy VS 2010 or is there any workaround so i can play around with these [samples](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need VS2010 to target .NET 4.0 but you could take a look at the [express version](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-gb/express) if cost is an issue.

The express version doesn't support extensions and therefore won't allow you to install the developer toolkit available in the SDK.  However, this isn't required for developing against CRM but does make the developer workflow considerably easier.  Worth taking a look if you do go for one of the paid versions of the VS product family.

Comment: Another option is to install the full version as a trial. That way, he can play with the good stuff for 60 days (which can be prolonged to 90 for absolutely free). Then, we also have VMs where one can reinstall the software and some sites... Hrmp... Well, there are other options, depending on the flexibility of the morale. :)